# SQL count an item per another variable

Tags: sql, count

I have a table named employees shown below. I am trying to get a count of Skill_nbr per Job. So Analyst has 2 Skill_nbr, Manager has 2 and Sr Analyst has 3.

[image: Table employees]

Comment: This post shows absolutely no effort on your part.  Have you Googled 'SQL Count Distinct'?

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
Select Job, Count (Distinct Skill_Nbr) NumberOfSkills
From Employees
Group by Job
```